# Can't save or update database data in SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I can't edit nor add any data in my database. I double checked my code but I cant find what go wrong. Im using PDO sql
Even when I add data, it didn't save into the database.
My code shows no error but whenever Im crosschecking mg logic, it was correct
Please help me with this one

here is my edit modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_<?php echo $rec['bookID']; ?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Book</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" action="editbook.php?id=<?php echo $rec['bookID']; ?>">
        <div class="modal-body">
      ISBN: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtIsbn" aria-describedby="ISBN" value="<?php echo $rec['isbn']; ?>">
      Title: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtTitle" aria-describedby="Title" value="<?php echo $rec['title']; ?>">
      Author: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtAuthor" aria-describedby="Author" value="<?php echo $rec['author']; ?>">
      Publisher: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtPublisher" aria-describedby="Publisher" value="<?php echo $rec['publisher']; ?>">
      Copyright Year: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtCYear" idaria-describedby="Copyright Year" value="<?php echo $rec['copyright_year']; ?>">
      Status: <select class="form-control" name="txtStatus" value="<?php echo $rec['status']; ?>">
          <option name="New">New</option>
          <option name="Old">Old</option>
          <option name="Damage">Damage</option>
          <option name="Archive">Archive</option>
          <option name="Lost">Lost</option>
          </select>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" name="edit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my code to edit modal

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->open();
    try{
        $bookID = $_GET['bookID'];
        $isbn=$_POST['txtIsbn'];
        $title=$_POST['txtTitle'];
        $author=$_POST['txtAuthor'];
        $publisher=$_POST['txtPublisher'];
        $copyright_year=$_POST['txtCYear'];
        $status=$_POST['txtStatus'];

        $sql = ("UPDATE books SET isbn='$isbn', title='$title', author='$author', publisher='$publisher', copyright_year='$copyright_year', status='$status' WHERE bookID='$bookID'");

        $_SESSION['message'] = ( $db->exec($sql) ) ? 'Member updated successfully' : 'Something went wrong. Cannot update member';

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $database->close();
}
else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Fill up edit form first';
}

header('location: editbook.php');?>
```

And here's my connection to database

```
<?php Class Connection{

private $server = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lms_db_main";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
private $options  = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,);
protected $dbConn;

public function open(){
    try{
        $this->dbConn = new PDO($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
        return $this->dbConn;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}

public function close(){
    $this->dbConn = null;
}}?>
```

And hers my table calling the data in database

```
 <tbody>
            <?php include_once('connection.php');

              $database = new Connection();
              $db = $database->open();
              try{  
                $sql = 'Select * from books';
                 foreach ($db->query($sql) as $rec){
              ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $rec['bookID']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['isbn']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['title']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['author']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['publisher']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['copyright_year']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rec['status']?></td>
              <td><a href="#edit_<?php echo $rec['bookID']; ?>" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a></td>
              <?php include('edit_modal.php'); ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
              }
             catch(PDOException $e){
              echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
              }
              $database->close();
              ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
```

What could be my missing code or did I miss something here?

Comment: Your `Connection` class contains no `exec` method. What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: I assuming that I have some mis-declared code in my edit code so Im not looking whether the connection was correct or not. What would you suggest?

Comment: Once more, your `exec` method is missing. How should we check it if you don't share it?

Comment: Ill already share my code to my connection, what would you suggest?

Comment: Well, if you are sure that your connection is built up properly, but you cannot modify data and you have not tried anything to debug the problem on your own, you should share that `exec` method such that we can suggest additional error checks

Comment: I already share exec, sorry I have some problem on my internet
I did call class connection to my table to populate the data on my data base

Comment: Where can I find the definition of `exec`? Its not in the given code

Comment: i separated the edit modal and the code to the edit modal

Comment: And why haven't you posted the definition of `exec` yet?

Comment: What definition of exec? Sorry I dont get it, I can populate or call the data on my database but cant edit them

Comment: You posted some code of your `Connection` class, but not the relevant code from the `exec` method. It's missing.

Comment: And my connection class was my connection to my database
and Im calling it on the tables.php
And exec method should be where?

Comment: So please guide me

Comment: Ah, okay - so your `Connection` class returns a `PDO` object. Wasn't obvious to me, sorry. So, what have you tried to debug this additionally? What does `exec` return in your case? Is the SQL query built correctly, such that you can execute it using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I return exec by the data of POST, the query is ok because I can show all the data of my database but I think I just miss some code on my edit code to query the updated data on my database
I tried to debug it by checking my declared variables, seems ok. tried also to emphasize the '' and "" because that might affect it, it seems not

Comment: Have you tried using the `UPDATE` query manually in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for PDO is not correct. Please try to follow below syntax to resolve the problem.

```
try{
      // data to be updated in id 1
        $title = 'Php Books';
        $author = 'Kuldeep';
        $id = 1;
      // query
        $sql = "UPDATE books SET title=?, author=? WHERE id=?";
        $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($title,$author,$id));

catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I did try that syntax but it seems that it is not working also. Im assuming that I dont need the query part because I declare the variable to open the database?

Comment: Ok, but other than that all seems fine. can you just try any static data instead of post data as i believe there might be have problem with you post  data because you are not using mysql real escape string function.

Comment: Static data returns an error, Im using POST method to fetch the data on the text box of my modal, but I think there was some error on my edit code because I can populate the data and show but cant update the data of my database

Comment: Just try like this $bookID = 121345; $isbn='XYZ114'; $title='sjdfksjdfs';

Comment: Not sure but might be helpful to track the issue.